# How to create dynamic bundle identifier in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm working on an app right now. The application is needed for many clients with less changes and different names(like color scheme, app name, app icon etc..). I've been doing this so far by maintaining a branch of my code with a different bundle identifier and bundle display name. I'm beginning to wonder if there may be an easier way to do this, though Can we dynamically create bundle identifier and display name programmatically?

Comment: You may do this by using targets, build configs and xcode schemes. There are a lot of guides out there that can help you achieve what you need

Comment: so I need to add multiple schemas and targets in my project to achieve this.

Comment: That, or create a base project that you import as an SDK for every new app you build